# How to find all the git commit id's for all the branches using git hub rest api url

Tags: git, rest, api, github, gitlab

I am trying to pull commit ids for all the branches using git hub rest api url. But I could see only the recent commit ids and don't see all the commit id's with respect to one branch.

Example url : https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits

Please help me to find the correct rest api url to pull all the commit ids for all branches.

Answer (score 1):

**The list of all commits in repository is paged**

See the returned header `Link` to get a URL of the next and last page.

Technically, add `?page=<number>` to query.

**If you need only commits in certain branch**

Thats a different story, and I don't believe, GitHub provides a way how to easily walk the repository. You may need to open the required reference:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref
```

gather SHA of the referenced object and traverse using:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:commit_sha
```

collecting "parents" along the way.

Comment: but in general, cloning the repository and using `git log` is much simpler

Comment: I tried GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref and GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:commit_sha url to pull all the commit details for particular branch . But I am able to get only recent commit details.

Comment: As I said, you need to traverse the reference, so: https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs/heads/master tells you that reference points to https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d and there you get the SHA of parents: https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/553c2077f0edc3d5dc5d17262f6aa498e69d6f8e and https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/762941318ee16e59dabbacb1b4049eec22f0d303 and so on...

Comment: As you said,I have traversed through the parents SHA and using this I am able to get all the commit details.I want to get all the commit details for particular branch dynamically .But with this option it is difficult as it is generating parent SHA for the last result set for particular branch which is pointing to the commit details of other branches.

Comment: @Ravi but that is how Git works internally. Reference (branch) points only to a commit, and commit only contains information on its immediate parents. If you consider this approach hard, clone the repository and use `git log`

Comment: Thanks petrpulc. We cannot use git log in production environment. So I have to go with git hub rest api approach . We are able to get all the commit details for particular branch with master details. Anyway can we filter out the master branch details while pulling data ?

Comment: As I said already. To get commits from certain reference (branch), use the information from API endpoint `.../git/refs/<reference>` to get SHA of newest commit and traverse across parents to gather all.

Endpoint `.../commits` will get you all accessible commit SHAs no matter in which branch they reside.